# ffmpeg Error "Output file #0 does not contain any stream"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

I'm new to this community and I have a question about ffmpeg. I'm making a python script to concatenate videos (especially mp4) using ffmpeg and I also used multiprocessing to speed up the process.

this is the function to read and process the video file:

```
def process_video(group_number):
    num_processes = mp.cpu_count()
    width, height, frame_count = get_video_frame_details(file_name)
    frame_jump_unit = frame_count // num_processes

    # read video file
    clip = cv.VideoCapture(file_name)

    clip.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_jump_unit * group_number)

    # get height, width and frame count of the video
    width, height = (
    int(clip.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
    int(clip.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    )

    no_of_frames = int(clip.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps = int(clip.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    proc_frames = 0

    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
    out = cv.VideoWriter()
    output_file_name = "Aktorik_sliced.mp4"
    out.open(output_file_name, fourcc, fps, (width, height), True)
    out.open("output_{}.mp4".format(group_number), fourcc, fps, (width, 
    height), True)
    try:
        while proc_frames < frame_jump_unit:
            ret, frame = clip.read()
            if not ret:
            break

    except:
        # Release resources
        clip.release()
        out.release()

    # Release resources
    clip.release()
    out.release()
```

This is the function to concatenate the videos:

```
def combine_output_files(num_processes):
    output_file_name = "Aktorik_sliced.mp4"

    # Create a list of output files and store the file names in a txt file
    list_of_output_files = ["output_{}.mp4".format(i) for i in 
    range(num_processes)]
    with open("list_of_output_files.txt", "w") as f:
        for t in list_of_output_files:
            f.write("file {} \n".format(t))

    # use ffmpeg to combine the video output files
    ffmpeg_cmd = "ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -f concat -safe 0 -i 
    list_of_output_files.txt -vcodec copy " + output_file_name
    sp.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, shell=True).wait()

    # Remove the temperory output files
    # for f in list_of_output_files:
    #    remove(f)
    # remove("list_of_output_files.txt")
```

And this is the function to call the multiprocess:

```
def multi_process():
    num_processes = mp.cpu_count()
    width, height, frame_count = get_video_frame_details(file_name)
    print("Video processing using {} processes...".format(num_processes))
    start_time = time.time()

    # Parallel the execution of a function across multiple input values
    p = mp.Pool(num_processes)
    p.map(process_video, range(num_processes))

    combine_output_files(num_processes)

    end_time = time.time()

    total_processing_time = end_time - start_time
    print("Time taken: {}".format(total_processing_time))
    print("FPS : {}".format(frame_count/total_processing_time))
```

In the end, this is what I got as an output:
[Output file #0 does not contain any stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icywu.png)

I've tried many things with this code, but I still got no clue where did I do wrong. It will be such a big help if somebody can help me :)

Thanks in advance!